# Bouncy Castle ECC Key Pair Generation produces different sizes for the coordinates of EC public key point

Tags: java, cryptography, compression, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve

I'm generating an ECC key pair with Bouncy Castle using :

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = null;
try {
    kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDH", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
    throw new CustomException("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
}

try {
    kpg.initialize(paramSpec, new SecureRandom());
} catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
    throw new CustomException("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
}

return kpg.generateKeyPair();
```

The type of `paramSpec` is `ECParameterSpec` from `java.security.spec`. I'm using `brainpoolP256r1`.

It works well. Then I want to convert the public key value from the key pair (X and Y coordinates from EC public point) to octet string.

To do that, I'm using `BigInteger.toByteArray()` function.

My question and what I'm trying to understand is why the size of coordinates is not always the same ?

It should be 32 bytes for each coordinate. But sometimes, I get 31 bytes or 33 bytes. From what I saw, it has to do with `toByteArray()` that returns a byte[] containing the two's-complement representation of this BigInteger. And the value of the coordinate is not filling fully 32 bytes.

For 33 bytes, I understood that I can safely get rid of the leftmost byte if its value is 0x00. But for 31 bytes ? Should I add 0x00 at the beginning to have 32 bytes ?

If someone can provide some explanation to understand better, it would be much appreciated. 
Maybe it has been addressed in another post, but I did not find through my research what I was looking for.

**EDIT**

The code that extracts the BigInteger values :

```
KeyPair aKeyPair = generateKeyPair(); //Function above
PublicKey publicKey = aKeyPair.getPublic();
byte[] X = ((ECPublicKey)publicKey).getW().getAffineX().toByteArray();
byte[] Y = ((ECPublicKey)publicKey).getW().getAffineY().toByteArray();
```

For example, X and Y once were :

00XX...XX : 32 bytes

00XX...XX : 33 bytes

Comment: I updated the post with how I extract the values.

Comment: If you pick a random number between 0 and 256, about 1/2 the time it will be less than 128. About 1/4 the time it will be less than 64, and so on. The same principle applies to your public keys. About 1/2^n of the time your public key X coordinates will be less than p/2^n. In other words, about one of every 256 times your X coordinate will have the 8 high-order bits equal to zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right that EC public key coordinates should be 32 bytes long(for 256 bits based curves). However when you are using [`BigInteger::toByteArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray--) documentations states that :

> The array will contain the minimum number of bytes required to represent this BigInteger, including at least one sign bit, which is {@code (ceil((this.bitLength() + 1)/8))}

So when you receive the 33 bytes it means that the highest bit was set to 1 and to preserve it as positive value, a byte with value `0` was appended. When there are 31 bytes for the coordinate it means that the highest byte could be skipped because it's value was 0 so the resulting byte array has 31 values and you should append one byte with value 0 as the highest byte. I made a small app to test it :

```
BigInteger affineX = ((ECPublicKey) publicKey).getW().getAffineX();

BigInteger affineY = ((ECPublicKey) publicKey).getW().getAffineY();

printCoordinateInfo(affineX, "X");
System.out.println();
printCoordinateInfo(affineY, "Y");
```

And utility methods to print coordinates :

```
private static void printCoordinateInfo(BigInteger bigInteger, String coordinateName) {
    String bitString = bigInteger.toString(2);
    String binary = fillZeros(bitString, 264);
    byte[] coordinateBytes = bigInteger.toByteArray();

    System.out.println(coordinateName + " byte array length " + coordinateBytes.length);
    System.out.println(coordinateName + " bit string length " + binary.length());
    System.out.println(binary);
}

private static String fillZeros(String text, int size) { //fills with zeros on the left and quits when achieves given length
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(text);
    while (builder.length() < size) {
        builder.insert(0, '0');
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

The output was :

```
X byte array length 32
X bit string length 264
0111010011001001010010110111101000000110010111001001100101101111101011001010101101000101101100111011000111000110101110010101101011000111100101000000010010110000010110111101100111110100000111010110001100001010111110011101111000010111010110011010000101001010

Y byte array length 33
Y bit string length 264
1000011111110111111100111101100101100101111001100110001111110101001101010001000110111011111000111001111010111111000000010011101001100010010010100111000110110001101100101110010110001100111001000001110101011101011100110110110010101001000010011101000000110000
```

What we can see :

- Coordinate `X` has byte array length 32. We print this BigInteger to bit string on 264 values so 8 zeros are appended on the beggining by `fillZeros` method. The 9'th bit from the left was 0 so we did not have to have addidional 33 byte for preserving sign.
- Coordinate `Y` has byte array length 33. We print it to bit string that will have 264 characters. The `fillZeros` method will not change the [`BigInteger::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString-int-) call as we already have string of length 264 from `BigInteger::toString`. **Notice that 9'th bit from left is 1 so `toByteArray` appended a byte with value 0 to preserve sign**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It makes things a lot clearer for me.